# How can I permanently disable the mounting of USB storage devices?

Tags: usb, transfer, unmount

I want to permanently disable the option to use USB storage devices. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to achieve now really, just un-mounting an USB or disabling USB use on your machine altogether?

Comment: i want to my OS to use USB's.

Comment: I mean i want to unmount all kin of removeable drives

Comment: Yep, but for ever (and in general) or just a single instance?

Comment: for ever ..... I don't want USB support in my OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the use of all USB sockets via your Motherboard UEFI or BIOS.

Steps to do this:

1. Shutdown your system.
2. Start it up again and press F1 or F2 to go into your motherboard BIOS/UEFI. This process is to happen before Ubuntu even boots up.
3. Once in side search for section on USBs and disable them or the relevant one.
4. Save your new settings and quit (this will reboot your system and you can test if the USBs would still work or not).

Best to you.